# Flutter Error: MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been trying to get the size of the whole context view in Flutter. But every time I try I'm getting the above mentioned error. 
Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: I also tried with a `StatefulWidget`. 
Please, help me find what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: How do you show the page?

Comment: void main() => runApp(new MyIntroductionPage());

Comment: Can you show the exact error?
PS: don't keep size as final, because it may change when you rotate the phone.

Comment: @ArnoldParge the exact error is given in the title itself.

Answer (score 105):

You need a `MaterialApp` or a `WidgetsApp` around your widget. They provide the `MediaQuery`. When you call `.of(context)` flutter will always look up the widget tree to find the widget.

You usually have this in your main.dart:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      theme: kThemeData,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      child: ...,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have just seen your edits. When you call MediaQuery.of(context), the MaterialApp must already be in the widget three.

Comment: I had same problem but just in first run i had this error and second run and more works correctly.

Comment: Encountered the same question as @MohammadMeshkani mentioned, error disappear at second run

Comment: Still i am having this problem.

Answer (score 26):

What works for us is using WidgetsBinding.instance.window instead of MediaQuery - also when setting the theme of the MaterialApp:

```
_pixelRatio = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio;
_screenWidth = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.width;
_screenHeight = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.height;
_statusBarHeight = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.padding.top;
_bottomBarHeight = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.padding.bottom;
_textScaleFactor = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.textScaleFactor;
```

Comment: two different result in `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.padding.top` and `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;`

Comment: @BloodLoss You can use `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewPadding` instead

Comment: `MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window)` gives you the same object back as `MediaQuery.of(context)` and it does the device pixel ratio calculations for you, which the above won't. Pretty much the same solution but with some extra fluff.

Comment: @Royston46 What kind of *device pixel ratio calculations* does `MediaQueryData.fromWindow` do? I just tested it and they both gave me the same number.

Answer (score 20):

You can access `MediaQuery` when you are inside `MaterialApp`. The place where you are accessing the media query is not correct.

Please refer below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CommonThings {
  static Size size;
}

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'MediaQuery Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CommonThings.size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    print('Width of the screen: ${CommonThings.size.width}');
    return new Container();
  }
}
```

I've purposely created a class `CommonThings` which has static Size so that you can use it throughout the app.

Answer (score 16):

I fixed it by using the following method. First I created a new class named `MyWidget` and returned it in `MyApp` within a `MaterialApp`'s `home:`. Refer code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyWidget(),
    );
  }
} 

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, declaring size as final doesn't matter. Orientation/Rotation is handled.

Comment: What a weird behaviour. Used WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize instead

Answer (score 12):

Solved by re-run the app(click on stop button in android studio then run again)

Comment: This will only work if you changed your code in between those runs.

Answer (score 5):

There is **better way**. Above solutions would require you to have **only one** screen widget **or inherit** all screens from parent class. **But there is solution**, place the media query initialization into onGenerateRoute callback function

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My Awesome App',
        routes: NavigationUtils.routeList(),
        onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) =>
          NavigationUtils.onGenerateRoute(routeSettings),
      );
    }
}
```

NavigationUtils.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavigationUtils {
    static onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {   
      return new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          WidgetUtils.me.init(context);
            return StorageUtils.me.isLogged() ? HomeScreen() : ForkScreen();
        },
        settings: routeSettings,
      );
    }
}
```

WidgetUtils.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WidgetUtils {
    MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
    double _screenWidth;
    double _screenHeight;
    double _blockSizeHorizontal;
    double _blockSizeVertical;

    init(BuildContext context) {
        _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
        screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
        screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
        blockSizeHorizontal = screenWidth / 100;
        blockSizeVertical = screenHeight / 100;
    }
}
```

Warning: It is not copy & paste code, there are some singletons etc. but you should get the point ;)

Answer (score 4):

Had the same error in

```
import 'screens/tasks_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TasksScreen();

  }
}
```

I solved it by:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/tasks_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TasksScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your code in a Material App widget. I also had the same issue as I forgot to use it and directly returned the scaffold.

In other words, your MediaQuery.of(context) should be inside the Material Widget. 
Material app -> scaffold -> MediaQuery.of(context)

Answer (score 3):

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyAppOne(),
    );
  }
}
class MyAppOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyAppOne>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
 
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
   return MaterialApp(
    
      home: Scaffold(
      body:HomePage(),
      ),
    );
   }

}


class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Container(
      height:size/2,
      color:Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        
    );
  }

}
```

YOU SHOULD TRY THIS I HAVE DONE IT.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to change the package then this error arise, 
so make sure you complete each of the following steps

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550358/4993045

Answer (score 0):

As WidgetsBinding.instance.window... is deprecated use FlutterView instead:

```
  static void _loadDeviceInfos() {
    FlutterView view = WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first;
    _pixelRatio = view.devicePixelRatio;
    _screenWidth = view.physicalSize.width;
    _screenHeight = view.physicalSize.height;
    _statusBarHeight = view.padding.top;
    _bottomBarHeight = view.padding.bottom;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Add MaterialApp ...

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}
```