# MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a media query. visual studio Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Good morning developers, after I finished my first app.... I just face a big issue

[here you can find the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Miqwc.jpg)
this issue is start showing after am trying to start moving the app to the phone

As you can see the img I don't know how to fix this problem

Thank You guys.

here is my code inside the main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './Signup.dart';
import 'package:adobe_xd/page_link.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          // Adobe XD layer: 'Main' (shape)
          Container(
            width: 375.5,
            height: 813.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: const AssetImage(''),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(58.0, 594.0),
            child: PageLink(
              links: [
                PageLinkInfo(
                  transition: LinkTransition.SlideLeft,
                  ease: Curves.easeOut,
                  duration: 0.3,
                  pageBuilder: () => Signup(),
                ),
              ],
              child: Container(
                width: 269.0,
                height: 42.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(77.0, 646.0),
            child: PageLink(
              links: [
                PageLinkInfo(
                  transition: LinkTransition.SlideLeft,
                  ease: Curves.easeOut,
                  duration: 0.3,
                  pageBuilder: () => Signup(),
                ),
              ],
              child: Container(
                width: 98.0,
                height: 22.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // This makes the visual density adapt to the platform that you run
        // the app on. For desktop platforms, the controls will be smaller and
        // closer together (more dense) than on mobile platforms.
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

I hope to find the solution to fix this and thank you...

Comment: You have to show your code bro... Plz add your upper most Widget... ie inside `runapp()`

Comment: are you using MediaQuery.of(context)? for example   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

Comment: I already puts my code now... I just use the adobe_xd to customize some small app

Comment: please guys.... help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Error: MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214338/flutter-error-mediaquery-of-called-with-a-context-that-does-not-contain-a-med)

Comment: @AzzamAlmesbahi, I have tested your code. wrap with MaterialApp can works fine. if you encounter further questions. you can ping my name to reopen. thank you very much.