# How can I use MediaQuery to build theme?

Tags: flutter, design-patterns

started to learn Flutter so I'm thinking if is it possible to create a function that returns a `ThemeData` object, but inside this function I wanna use `MediaQuery.of(context)`. I mean, I know I can create such a function, but if I use `MediaQuery.of(context)` inside of it, I have an error
`(MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery)` complaining about the missing of MediaQueryProvider. I know I can use MediaQuery in child elements of MaterialApp, but I have a design problem now. Imagine this:

```dart
ThemeData getTheme(BuildContext context) {
  // I wanna be able to call MediaQuery.of(contex) here
  return ThemeData();
}

MaterialApp(
   home: home,
   // the getTheme() must be able to use MediaQuery. It takes a context and returns a ThemeData object
   theme: theme.getTheme(context),
   routes: routes,
)
```

Is there a way to do it? or event better, Should I do it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Error: MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214338/flutter-error-mediaquery-of-called-with-a-context-that-does-not-contain-a-med)

Comment: well, i'm think not, the link helped me to understand the problem, but it does not help to find a solution

Comment: Ok. I will have a deeper look later.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is not using the `theme` property of `MaterialApp` but wrapping the descendants with a `Theme` widget using the `builder` property. It will have the `MaterialApp` as an ancestor so you can use `MediaQuery` there.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Theme(
      data: getTheme(context), // you can use MediaQuery.of(context) in the called function
      child: child,
    );
  },
  home: HomeScreen(),
  // etc, no theme here
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the brotherhood.
Actually, to call for `MediaQuery` you will need to wrap your main widget with a `MaterialApp()` which usually is done in your main.dart file.
Here is an example:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it does solve my design problem, i think i will try the @madhavam-shahi  solution, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Create a stateless/ stateful widget for the `home` of your `MaterialApp`, and inside that, create your `getTheme` method.

Example,

```
homePage extends StatelessWidget{

ThemeData getTheme(BuildContext context) {
  // Call MediaQuery.of(contex) here
  return ThemeData();
}

@override
//build method

}//homePage ends here.
```

Now, in your material app, simple call that method.

```
MaterialApp(
   home: homePage(),
  
   theme: homePage().getTheme(context),
   routes: routes,
)
```

Comment: First I would like to thanks you, but sorry it didn't work for me. I am able to make it works using something like this: 1) listen to a build event of a child using a function that takes a child context, so in this function I call setState to assign a class filed a new theme that is passed to MaterialApp. It works, but I really don`t like this Design