# How to set MediaQuery textScaleFactor throughout the application and not for each page

Tags: flutter, dart

#### Main

```
final query = MediaQuery.of(context);

return MediaQuery(
  data: query.copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.4),
  child: MaterialApp(
     title: "Flutter Demo",
     initialRoute: '/loginPage',
  )
);
```

```
 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (13775): The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#38690):
I/flutter (13775): MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
I/flutter (13775): No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of().
I/flutter (13775): This can happen because you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce
I/flutter (13775): a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.
```

With the **MediaQuery** class and its **data** property, I would like to condition the **textScaleFactor** for the whole application, however I can not get a context before a **MaterialApp**...

So I don't want to go for each page I have adding the class like *parent*, how could I can add the class only once for the whole application?

#### LoginPage (it works but i don't want this)

```
final query = MediaQuery.of(context);

return MediaQuery(
  data: query.copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.4),
  child: Scaffold(
     [...]
  );
```

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Error: MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214338/flutter-error-mediaquery-of-called-with-a-context-that-does-not-contain-a-med)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50225819/4679965

Comment: No, because I have to do it on each page, for example I have 10 main pages, I'm not going to do it 10 times, is there any way to do it globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I was able to solve it in the following way without using another MaterialApp or WidgetsApp.

```
      MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey, // here
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
        [...]
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
            textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context)
                .textScaleFactor
                .clamp(1.0, 1.4),
          ),
          child: child ?? const SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
      ),
```

Create a global variable in my route generator file and only call it in the app material

```
[...]
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class RouteGenerator {
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to wrap MaterialApp with another MaterialApp and set [useInheritedMediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/useInheritedMediaQuery.html):

```
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, _) { # builder so we can access MaterialApp context
          final query = MediaQuery.of(context);
          return MediaQuery(
              data: query.copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.4),
              child: MaterialApp( 
                  useInheritedMediaQuery: true, #inherited MediaQuery will be used
                  ....
```

Another way is to use `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize` https://stackoverflow.com/a/60415290/4679965

Comment: It doesn't show any error, but it doesn't work like that apparently, it doesn't read the MediaQuery data, and also my attributes of the second MaterialApp, for example debugShowCheckedModeBanner.

Comment: Also the problem with `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize` is that it doesn't have the copyWith for the MediaQuery

Comment: Need to add `useInheritedMediaQuery: true` param, updated answer

Comment: Oh, okey, well, i don't have my Flutter updated to 2.0 so... xD but thx anyways !